# stretched out ref hyperlink in alignat-environment

Tags: alignat

I have the following problem. In one equation, I'm trying to use some short notation and thus reference an earlier equation (label). The problem is that the hyperlink box is stretched over the entire alignat box. I tried adding a linebreak after the 1st part of the equation, but that only breaks the alignment.

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
   &\gamma^0 (\ref{eq:kinetic-homo2}) \gamma^0 + (\ref{eq:kinetic-homo2})^\dagger 
   \begin{aligned}[t]
       &=~ 2 \Big( m^2 - k^2 - \frac{1}{4} (\partial + q F \cdot \partial^{(p)})^2 \Big) \gamma^0 W^E(x,k) \gamma^0 \
       &=~ \frac{1}{8} q F_{\mu\nu} \gamma^0 \Big( \sigma^{\mu \nu} W^E(x,k) + W^E(x,k) \sigma^{\mu \nu} \Big) \gamma^0 \
       &=~ \frac{1}{8} q F_{\mu\nu} \gamma^0 { \sigma^{\mu \nu}, W^E(x,k) } \gamma^0
    \end{aligned}\
    &\Leftrightarrow~ \Big( m^2 - k^2 - \frac{1}{4} (\partial + q F \cdot \partial^{(p)})^2 \Big) W^E(x,k) ~=~ \frac{1}{16} q F_{\mu\nu} { \sigma^{\mu \nu}, W^E(x,k) }
\end{alignat}
```

[image: the code]

[image: the way it looks]

How do I change this such that the hyperlink boxes are not stretched out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: Switch to text mode for the reference with `\mbox{\ref{eq:kinetic-homo2}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I was about to change my code snippet, but Ulrike Fischer's comment fixed my issue already. Finally no stretched hyperlink boxes.